# Error while configuring conda activate on powershell using "conda init"

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda, conda

I tried to use the command `conda activate`

It threw me an error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
```

So I tried `conda init powershell`. which threw me another error:

Note: I have tried this running in Administrator mode also.

```
PS C:\Users\Ashin> conda init powershell
WARNING: Cannot install xonsh wrapper without a python interpreter in prefix: C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\Scripts\conda.exe
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\Scripts\conda-env.exe
modified      C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\Scripts\conda-script.py
modified      C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\Scripts\conda-env-script.py
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\condabin\conda.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\Library\bin\conda.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\condabin\_conda_activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\condabin\rename_tmp.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\condabin\conda_auto_activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\condabin\conda_hook.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\Scripts\activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\condabin\activate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\condabin\deactivate.bat
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\Scripts\activate
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\Scripts\deactivate
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\etc\profile.d\conda.sh
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\etc\fish\conf.d\conda.fish
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
needs sudo    C:\Users\Ashin\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI195762\etc\profile.d\conda.csh
modified      C:\Users\Ashin\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1

==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==

Operation failed.
```

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use the anaconda prompt instead of cmd.exe to run conda commands

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved by using `conda init powershell` from the anaconda prompt packaged with miniconda.